# 何だこの中二心に響くサウンドは Does この refer to サウンド? How does に and an intransitive verb work?

Tags: syntax, particle-に

Is この refering to サウンド or 中二心? 
How does に and an intransitive verb work together?
My translation attempt is: What is this sound that resonates with my chuuni heart?

Answer (score 3):

> Is この referring to サウンド or 中二心? How does に and an intransitive verb work together? My translation attempt is: What is this sound that resonates with my chuuni heart?

The この refers to サウンド. The basic structure of this sentence is 「何だ、このサウンドは？」 (= Inversion of 「このサウンドは何だ？」, "What is this sound?")
The に is an indirect object marker. 響く is an intransitive verb and can take an indirect object.

「サウンドが心に響く」 = *lit.* "A sound resounds/echos through one's heart" → "A sound/tune/music resonates with / touches one's heart"

So I think your translation is good.

> 「何だこの中二心に響くサウンドは（？）」
>   "What is this sound/tune/music that resonates with / touches my chuuni heart?"
>   <sub>(... with a nuance of exclamatory "What a (touching) sound/tune/music this is!")</sub>

Answer (score 0):

この refers to 中二心. The に tells you location where 響くis happening.

A reasonable translation would be: What! The sound that resonates in this chuuni heart...